# Can we have uppercase and lowercase tags?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

There is this question lately on the Christianity.SE. It asks for "orthodox Christianity". I edited it, so that the question would be more focused toward one specific branch of Christianity - Eastern Orthodox Christianity, since the name suggests that the Eastern Orthodox is *orthodox*. Still, I wish there is a tag that says [orthodox-christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthodox-christianity) that is separated from a tag that says [orthodox-christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthodox-christianity), and maybe allow [orthodox-christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthodox-christianity) be a synonym of [eastern-orthodoxy](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eastern-orthodoxy).

Comment: Hmm. I think your tags in the question illustrate the point!

Answer (score 5):

Besides not wanting this for the normal reasons tags are not cased, I think this would only serve to confuse the issue.

- *Nobody* would pay a bean of attention to the difference between two tags that were the same except case. I realize the distinction between the terms in Christianity but in the case of a tag the name needs to be more self explanatory.
- If we did have a separate tag for the lower-case-o meaning, it would be [orthodoxy](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthodoxy), and the tag for the capital-o meaning is already [eastern-orthodoxy](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eastern-orthodoxy) as it should be. That being said I don't think we currently have a constructive use for the former anyway.

In any event, no we cannot have upper-cased tags and we can't have tags for things we don't have questions for, so this is kind of a moot point.

Comment: The problem with "orthodoxy" is the retort "And what is orthodox?" which is Truthy and off-topic.

Comment: @Andrew Reminds me of a short essay I read from an Orthodox Jewish Rabbi. He insisted that there is no such thing as Orthodox Judaism; just Judaism and everything else.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Hence why I can't think of constructive questions that need the tag. If talking about it in the abstract something like [tag:doctrine] is more likely to fit anyway.

Comment: Can you merge [tag:orthodoxy] and [tag:eastern-orthodoxy] then?

Comment: @Anonymous I'm pretty sure they already are.

Comment: @Anonymous they already are. [I asked them to be merged over a year ago.](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1480/1304)

Comment: And @Caleb if you could tag that (^^^^) [meta-tag:status-completed] that would be good (I can't as a non-mod).